# How to re-render a table with Livewire after an event emitted from another component

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, livewires

I'm new to Livewire and I am stuck with this problem.

I've created a *table.blade.php* component with livewire, and another searchbar.blade.php component, which is not a child of the table component. Every time a search for a  term, the table should rerender with the seached parameter.

All is right, and the search query gives the correct result (clients with pagination), but somehow the table does not rerender the html.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

```
<div>
    <input type="text" wire:model="query" autofocus>
</div>
```

```
class SearchBar extends Component
{
    public $query;


    public function updatedQuery()
    {
        $this->emit('searchForQuotes', $this->query);
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.clients.searchbar');
    }
}
```

```
<div>
    <table>
        <tbody>
        @foreach($clients as $client)
            @livewire('clients.row', ['client' => $client], key($client->id))
        @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

```
class Table extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;

    public $query;

    protected $listeners = [
        'searchForQuotes' => 'render'
    ];

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->resetData();
    }

    public function resetData()
    {
        $this->query = null;
    }

    public function render($query = null)
    {
        $q = Client::query();

        if ($query) {
            $q->whereRaw("CONCAT(surname, ' ', name) LIKE '%" . $query . "%'");
        }

        $clients = $q->latest()->paginate(20);

        return view('livewire.clients.inc.table', [
            'clients' => $clients, 'query' => $query
        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make your child components reactive by making your `key()` unique every render of the parent:

```html
@livewire('clients.row', ['client' => $client], key($client->id . "-" . Str::random()))
```

By adding a `Str::random()`, the key is different every time the parent updates, which forces the children to update as well. This also works with `now()`, but only as long as you have a prefix. It is important to note that this causes more requests and thus can make your table slower.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
class Table extends Component
{
use WithPagination;

public $query;

protected $listeners = ['searchForQuotes'];

public function mount()
{
    $this->resetData();
}

public function searchForQuotes($query)
{
    $this->query = $query; 
    // Do something
    $this->render();
}

public function resetData()
{
    $this->query = null;
}

public function render()
{
    $q = Client::query();

    if ($this->query) {
      $q->whereRaw("CONCAT(surname, ' ', name) LIKE '%" . $query . "%'");
    }

    $clients = $q->latest()->paginate(20);

    return view('livewire.clients.inc.table', [
        'clients' => $clients, 'query' => $this->query
    ]);
}
}
```

Comment: Unfortunatly it doesn't work. If I dd($clients) in the render() method of the table component (after searching the term), I can see all of the clients searched, than means that the search process is working well. Somehow it does not render anything, and the table gets empty after the search!

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the problem, but don't know how to solve it.
I the table.blade.php component I've got this code.

```
@foreach($clients as $client)
   @livewire('clients.row', ['client' => $client], key($client->id))
@endforeach
```

It seems like the nested component are not rendering after firing the event.

Comment: I found the problem, but don't understand the logic. The problem is in the key(). If the key is the same, the component does not render. If I use key($client->id . now()) it works

Comment: does this post describe how your solved it? Or is most of that in the comment?

Comment: I solved writing key($client->id . now())  - adding a fresh key with now() while rendering- to the child components.

Comment: It would help if you edited this answer with that information. It currently doesn’t read much like an answer.